# How to retry a specific request in multiple call using axios.all if one is faild

Tags: javascript, axios, promise

I make calls based on an array using axios and Promise.all,
sometimes there is an element that fails because I make a lot of calls (server problem)
I would like to retry the call for the element that fails after 10 min for example and continue

if a call element returns a 403 error for example I would like to retry this call for this element after 10 min and continue

```
class Service {

  async getElement(current) {
    return await axiosInstance
      .get(
        `/api/${current}/}`,
     
      )
      .then(res => {
       
        return res ;
      })
      .catch(async e => {
        
       
        return { el: null };
      });
  }
}

const getElementPromise = array.map(async item=> {
    return await Service.getElement(item).then(async result => {
        if (!result) {
          return {
            ref: null,
          };
        }
        return result;
      });
  });

 let ElementContent =[];
 
  await axios
    .all(getElementPromise)
    .then(res => {
      ElementContent= JSON.stringify(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: You can `setInterval` of 10 minutes and if you get the result from api, you can call `clearInterval`